# Setting x-axis as Year from datetime index of dataframe column using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here's a simplified version of the code which explains what I'm trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), index = dates, columns =list ('A'))

plt.plot(df['A'])
```

this results in this graph:

[image]

I want to use the Year from the datetime index as the labels for the x axis on this graph, not the number of datapoints/days. I want 2007, 2008, 2009 etc **based on the datetime index** (as this will vary according to my input data).

I've looked at every help site for this and nothing seems to work, I may be missing something very obvious, which I apologise for, but I can't figure this out.

**EDIT**

New code to illustrate error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), columns =list ('A'))
df['date'] = dates

def get_season(row):
    if row['date'].month >= 3 and row['date'].month <= 5:
        return 'spring'
    elif row['date'].month >= 6 and row['date'].month <= 8:
        return 'summer'
    elif row['date'].month >= 9 and row['date'].month <= 11:
        return 'autumn'
    else:
        return 'winter'

df['Season'] = df.apply(get_season, axis=1)
df['Year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df.loc[df['date'].dt.month == 12, 'Year'] += 1
df = df.set_index(['Year', 'Season'], inplace=False)

df.head()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x_compat=True,ax=ax)

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(reset=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))

plt.show()
```

This gives the error:

```
ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1
```

This seems to come from the line

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1))
```

I think it's to do with the multi-index, but don't understand how to plot it with the multi-index.

Answer (score 6):

You can plot directly from the `DataFrame` using [`df.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), index = dates, columns =list ('A'))

df.plot()

plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To just show the year, we need to turn off the default `pandas` date formatting, by setting `x_compat=True`.

Then, we can use a [`DateLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateLocator) and [`DateFormatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter) from [`matplotlib.dates`](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html) to just use the year.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

dates = pd.date_range('20070101',periods=1000)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), index = dates, columns =list ('A'))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(x_compat=True,ax=ax)

ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(reset=True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, this works, but the data I'm actually using is indexed by both year and season, and these overlap each other when graphed. Is there a way of only using one aspect of the index (i.e. the year) to label the x axis?

Comment: thanks again, but I'm still hitting an error when it gets to the  `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator(1))` line. The error says `ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1`. I thought this was because I was plotting only one column from the data frame, but when I create a new dataframe with only one column which I want, then try to plot that, the same error comes up.

Comment: maybe you should create a minimal example that actually reproduces your error?

Comment: Thanks! I used your code, and edit it to fit my needs, which is in MONTH ->>>>>>>>>>> new_hash_per_day_plot.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
new_hash_per_day_plot.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%m'))

Comment: @tom , In your first plot you are using df.plot(), that automatically set the xlabel in two rows (months and years), I am trying to do that without using df.plot() because I have using plt.subplots(), so do you know how do xlabel in two rows (months/years) using matplotlib.dates ?